# formation of table by looping table with an onclick function for each <td>..how?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

this is my code to create table with php by looping  ..i want to add an onclick function in each ..so that on clicking a particular cell the background color is changed..but m getting an error.
m i doing something wrong ??

```
<head>

<script>
function changeColor(elem)
{     
elem.style.background = "red";     
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<?php
$rows = 10; // define number of rows
$cols = 4;// define number of columns

echo "<table border='1'>";

for($tr=1;$tr<=$rows;$tr++){

    echo "<tr>";
        for($td=1;$td<=$cols;$td++){
               echo "<td onclick=\"changeColor(this)\" > ".$tr." ".$td."</td>";
        }
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Escape the double-quotes. The line should be: `echo "<td onclick=\"changeColor(this)\" > ".$tr." ".$td."</td>";`

Comment: ty fr pointing out d mistake...but still my cells are not getting selected..!!

Comment: What Amal showed you worked for me, as did Niko's and techfoobar's answers. @jasmin

Comment: @jacob: Two similar answers have been posted since the comment, and jasmin already accepted [one of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21200169/) - I don't see why a new answer is necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `echo` statement does not escape the quotes

```
echo "<td onclick="changeColor(this)" > ".$tr." ".$td."</td>";
```

change to this:

```
echo  echo "<td onclick='changeColor(this)'> $tr $td </td>";
```

One thing PHP replaces variables with their values when they are placed inside double quotes. So you do not need any concantenation when your using variables inside double quotes

Answer (score 3):

You missed escaping the quotes. It should be:

```
echo "<td onclick=\"changeColor(this)\" > ".$tr." ".$td."</td>";
```

Or you can use single quotes for the `onclick` attribute:

```
echo "<td onclick='changeColor(this)' > ".$tr." ".$td."</td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
for($td=1;$td<=$cols;$td++)
{
?>

<td onclick="changeColor(this)" ><?php echo $tr." ".$td;?></td>
<?php
}
```

seprate html from php code